# Copy data from Word to Excel Cell. Then trigger formula in adjacent cell. How?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a VBA code which moves data from Word to specific Excel Cell. In Excel sheet, there is formula which is triggered by the number inserted from word file. 
There formula is placed in next column to the column where I insert data from Word.

Code for copying data from Word works well, but after the insertion the formula is not triggered. Formula works fine if I insert number manually.

Do you have idea why formula is not triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the format of the cell?

Comment: Sorry I found the problem. There was space inserted in Word and Data was copied with this space, so formula was not triggered. the solution would be to use Trim formula in Excel to avoid this mistake in the future.